# Подключиться к H2 (in-memory) из IDEA

Tags: база-данных, intellij-idea, h2

Я понимаю что процесс IDEA не тот который создавал БД, и мне нужен обходной путь.
Я успешно поднимаю сервер консоль и у меня получается сделать коннект к БД из браузера там таблицы и данные которые ожидаю увидеть все ок.
НО при коннекте из IDEA, не получается... я проверил и jdbc драйвер версии и все мельчайшие детали... в чем дело у кого был такой же опыт?
введите сюда описание изображения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверить версию драйвера на соответствие с вашей версией java и проверить чтобы в pom файле была версия такая же , как в datasources
2. поднять сервак, но не createWebServer, а createTcpServer.
3. при поднятии сервака указать нстройки отдельно, а не одной строкой, тоесть вот так: Server.createTcpServer("-tcp","-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092"), а не вот так: Server.createTcpServer("-tcp,-tcpAllowOthers,true,-tcpPort, 9092"), ошибок не будет, но работать тоже не будет.
4. Наслаждаться коннектом по адресу jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:test